# disable auto-generated error pages iisexpress

Tags: web-config, iis-express

I'm creating a JSON web api. Certain parts of the api are limited to authenticated users only.

If you're not authenticated, the server is programmed to set the http status code to 403 and close the response.

```
http_response_code(403);
exit();
```

If that's the output my code produces, I don't expect iisexpress to jump in and serve an auto-generated html page. How can this behaviour be disabled?

I have tried adding following configuration to web.config

```
<httpErrors>
    <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
</httpErrors>
```

That doesn't work. Even if it did, only 4xx and 5xx status codes can be removed, and I need all auto-generated pages to be removed.

As suggested in a comment, I tried customerrors

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="index.php">
    <error statusCode="403" redirect="index.php"/>
</customErrors>
```

I still get the default 403 page.

Also note that I'm not actually being redirected (no 'Location' headers are being set) to the default 403 page. It's just rendering a default html page in my response.

Comment: Did you look at the `<customErrors>` Element? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @Sashenka I've just tried, but it doesn't seem to make any difference

Comment: I'm out of ideas then, I always worked with `<customErrors>` without any problems. I'll look around for more infos.

Comment: I appreciate it. I may have to move to apache if I can't find a solution.